# Can i use SQL CE database in an UWP app?

Tags: c#, sql-server-ce, uwp

As i can see from tutorials the typical option is SQLite. I'd like to use SQL Compact instead as i am about to port an existing app. Is it possible? Thanks!

Comment: I do not believe that this can be done as Microsoft.Data.SqlClient is not available on UWP. There may be a way to cludge this into working, but I would suggest sticking with SQLite for the sake of simplicity. Is there a specific reason you do not wish to use SQLite, or it is just personal preference?

Comment: I'm weighting the costs of porting my app to UWP currently. So i have to switch to a different db engine. And may i ask another question, does Linq to SQL work with SQLite?

Comment: I haven't tried it I'm afraid, but this might be of use to you - https://www.devart.com/dotconnect/sqlite/articles/tutorial_linq.html

Comment: Also worth looking at [Entity Framework 7](https://ef.readthedocs.org/en/latest/getting-started/uwp.html) If you're coming from a Linq-to-SQL environment like Windows Phone (Silverlight)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot use SQL Server Compact with UWP, but you can use SQLite and the sqlite-net wrapper, which enable "LINQ to SQL" like functionality.

Comment: ...or Entity Framework 7 which is really close (but still subtly different)

Comment: isnt EF just an ORM?